# How might I escape Unicode characters in a JSON string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, string

JSON String:

```
{
  "id":31896,

  "name":"Zickey attitude - McKinley,
   La Rosi\u00e8re,
   21 ao\u00fbt 2006",
...

}
```

this causes an unterminated string in JavaScript.

My attempt at a solution is:

```
data.replace(/(\S)\1(\1)+/g, '');
```

or

```
data.replace(/\\u([0-9A-Z])/, '');
```

any ideas/solution?

Example:
http://api.jamendo.com/get2/id+name+url+stream+album_name+album_url+album_id+artist_id+artist_name/track/jsonpretty/track_album+album_artist/?n=13&order=ratingmonth_desc&tag_idstr=jazz

last node is the problem, fyi.

```
(/\\u([0-9A-Z])/, '\1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the unicode escapes, but the unescaped newlines.

```
{
    "id":31896,
    "name":"Zickey attitude - McKinley,\nLa Rosi\u00e8re,\n21 ao\u00fbt 2006"
}
```

Comment: how to solve it?
i can not access a loop to select just the names and replace with \\n \\r what ever the newlines?

Answer (score 1):

well, the error occures only when using jsonpretty :).

shame on me ;)